# Unable to run Re-Index Tree - Process cannot access the file write.lock

Tags: lucene

I'm having problems running the Re-Index Tree command. After a few seconds I see: `An error occured while communicating with the Sitecore server: A network error occurred.`, followed by an empty error box. My network is actually okay and I can open Sitecore items fine on this server. It seems like no error happens in the logs when the command is run, however I do see this error message earlier:

```
ManagedPoolThread #8 14:46:00 ERROR Exception
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.Job.ThreadEntry(Object state)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.AggregateException
Message: One or more errors occurred.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[TLocal](Int32 fromInclusive, Int32 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEachWorker[TSource,TLocal](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Action`3 bodyWithStateAndIndex, Func`4 bodyWithStateAndLocal, Func`5 bodyWithEverything, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`2 body)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.PerformUpdate(IEnumerable`1 indexableInfo, IndexingOptions indexingOptions)

Nested Exception

Exception: Lucene.Net.Store.LockObtainFailedException
Message: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SitecoreCMS\Data\indexes\sitecore_web_index_sec\write.lock: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SitecoreCMS\Data\indexes\sitecore_web_index_sec\write.lock' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at Lucene.Net.Store.NativeFSLock.Obtain() in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Store\NativeFSLockFactory.cs:line 240
Source: Lucene.Net
   at Lucene.Net.Store.Lock.Obtain(Int64 lockWaitTimeout) in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Store\Lock.cs:line 97
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.Init(Directory d, Analyzer a, Boolean create, IndexDeletionPolicy deletionPolicy, Int32 maxFieldLength, IndexingChain indexingChain, IndexCommit commit) in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Index\IndexWriter.cs:line 1228
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter..ctor(Directory d, Analyzer a, Boolean create, MaxFieldLength mfl) in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Index\IndexWriter.cs:line 1019
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Sharding.LuceneShard.CreateWriter(Directory directory, LuceneIndexMode mode)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneUpdateContext.InitializeWriter(UpdateContextShardState shardState, LuceneIndexMode mode)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneUpdateContext.InitializeWriters()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneUpdateContext.EnsureInitializeWriters()
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneUpdateContext.UpdateDocument(Object itemToUpdate, Object criteriaForUpdate, IExecutionContext[] executionContexts)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.UpdateItemVersion(IProviderUpdateContext context, Item version, IndexEntryOperationContext operationContext)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.DoUpdate(IProviderUpdateContext context, SitecoreIndexableItem indexable, IndexEntryOperationContext operationContext)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.Update(IProviderUpdateContext context, IIndexableUniqueId indexableUniqueId, IndexEntryOperationContext operationContext, IndexingOptions indexingOptions)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.AbstractSearchIndex.<>c__DisplayClass93_2.<PerformUpdate>b__0(IndexableInfo info, ParallelLoopState parallelLoopState)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass17_0`1.<ForWorker>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )

Nested Exception

Exception: System.IO.IOException
Message: The process cannot access the file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SitecoreCMS\Data\indexes\sitecore_web_index_sec\write.lock' because it is being used by another process.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at Lucene.Net.Store.NativeFSLock.Obtain() in d:\Lucene.Net\FullRepo\trunk\src\core\Store\NativeFSLockFactory.cs:line 240
```

What can I do to further troubleshoot or solve this issue? We are on Sitecore 8.2 rev. 161115.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but do you happen to accidentally have multiple Sitecore instances running that are using the same data folder?

Comment: Sometimes antivirus software or the Windows Indexer can lock files. Might be worth disabling automatic indexing in that directory, restart computer, then try again and monitor.

Comment: Also just to jump in, maybe an IIS reset (simple i know) will do the trick of freeing up whatever has a lock on it (if not anti virus like @jrap says). cheers.

Comment: There is only one instance on each server. Two servers in a load balancer but they only look at their own data folder. There is no antivirus running on this server (it's a production server) and I checked the C:\ drive - indexing is not enabled. Can't do an IIS reset - looks like 'iis' is not recognized even in an elevated command prompt (may not have permission).

Comment: Is this occurring on both servers? Can you check the logs of both independently? Also, is it possible to stop the website/app pool on one server since they are load balanced and see if that frees it up? Or at least gives you a window to go delete the write.lock file.

Comment: I've had similar issues with Lucene and usually fixed them by deleting the index files and rebuilding. If you can't wait for a rebuild, copying the index files (after the delete) from another instance sometimes worked.

Comment: looks like the write.lock is not released correctly, If this is not a repeating issue. delete the lock file.

Comment: This is happening on both servers from what I can tell. I'll try all of your suggestions and hope to get back to you today - thanks!

Comment: So it turns out, that write.lock error message isn't happening when I try to re-index tree. In fact, there is no error in the logs at all. I checked the index files on both servers (with Show hidden files enabled) and the write.lock file mentioned in the error is no longer there. I'll try backing up and deleting index files from one server now and rebuilding to see if this works.

Comment: Deleted the `sitecore_web_index` and `sitecore_web_index_sec` folders under `/indexes`, rebuilt web index on both servers and still happening with no errors in the logs around the time I tried to run the `Re-Index Tree` command